# javafx CheckBoxTableCell always unchecked

Tags: generics, javafx-8

I am new to javafx. I try to display a CheckBoxTableCell but its always unchecked ignoring the Datamodel. That is how i create the column:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> createTableColumn(Class<T> type, String fieldName, String index, String columnHeader) {
    TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<S, T>(columnHeader);
    col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        try {
            Object o = ReflectionUtils.getValue(fieldName, cellData.getValue());
            // Erzeuge eine Property, die das Attribut enthält
            SimpleObjectProperty<T> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<T>((T) o);
            return property;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
    if (type.equals(Boolean.TYPE))
        ((TableColumn<S, Boolean>) col).setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn((TableColumn<S, Boolean>) col));

    col.setId(index);
    return col;
}
```

I have looked into CheckBoxTableCell and found that the factoryFunction i am using transforms to

```
    public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S,Boolean>, TableCell<S,Boolean>> forTableColumn(
        final TableColumn<S, Boolean> column) {
    return forTableColumn(null, null);
}
```

so i know why this function is not working but I dont know which way to use now.
I hope you can help me.

Minimal executable example:
My TableGenerator:

```
package company.viewfx.tables;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean;

import company.viewfx.annotations.AsTableColumn;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

/**
 *         Wrapperklasse, die die Benutzung des JavaFX TableView erleichtern soll
 * @param <S> Die Klasse, die in der Tabelle dargestellt werden soll
 */
@Log4j2
public class GTableView<S> extends TableView<S> {
    /**
     * Enthält eine Listen von Attributen aus <S> die in der Tabelle dargestellt werden sollen (optional)
     */
    @Setter
    private String[] attributes = new String[0];
    /**
     * Die Klasse die dargestellt werden soll
     */
    private Class<S> clazz;

    /**
     * @param clazz Die Klasse die dargestellt werden soll
     * @param items eine ObservableList<S> von Datenelementen
     */
    public GTableView(Class<S> clazz, ObservableList<S> items) {
        super(items);
        this.clazz = clazz;
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Fügt die Spalten + Überschrift und Inhalt zu der rohen Tabelle hinzu
     */
    private void initialize() {
        getColumns().addAll(process(attributes, "", "", this.clazz));
        // Spalten nach Id sortieren
        getColumns().sort(new Comparator<TableColumn<S, ?>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(TableColumn<S, ?> o1, TableColumn<S, ?> o2) {
                return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Process the model class.
     * For the fields declared which have annotation AsTableColumn, create a TableColumn<T,S>
     * instance for it with the detected field type.
     * 
     * @param attrList Eine Liste mit Attributen die angezeigt werden sollen (kann auch null sein, dann standard)
     * @param containerName Entscheidet in welchem Komplexen Attribut nach den Spalten gesucht wird
     * @param containerIndex Der index des entsprechenden Wurzelobjektes
     * @param clazz Die Klasse des Attributes, das in dieser Spalte dargestellt werden soll
     * @return Eine Listen von TableColumns für die mit @AsColumn in this.clazz markierten Attribute
     */
    public static <S> List<TableColumn<S, ? extends Object>> process(String[] attrList, String containerName, String containerIndex,
            Class<?> clazz) {
        // Der Rückgabenwert
        List<TableColumn<S, ? extends Object>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        // Wenn der Index nicht leer ist hänge einen Punkt an
        containerIndex += !containerIndex.equals("") ? "." : "";
        // Wenn der ContainerName nicht leer ist hänge einen Punkt an
        containerName += !containerName.equals("") ? "." : "";
        // Wenn die StandardSpalten verwendet werden sollen
        if (attrList.length == 0) {
            // gehe erst alle Felder durch
            for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                // Wenn das Attribut als Feld angezeigt werden soll
                if (field.isAnnotationPresent(AsTableColumn.class)) {
                    AsTableColumn anno = field.getAnnotation(AsTableColumn.class);
                    columns.add(createTableColumn(field.getType(), containerName + field.getName(), containerIndex + anno.index(),
                            anno.text()));
                }
            }
        }
        return columns;
    }

    /**
     * @param type Der Typ des Attributes, das in der Spalte stehen soll
     * @param fieldName Das Attribut, das in dieser Spalte dargestellt werden soll
     * @param columnHeader Die Spaltenüberschrift
     * @param index Der index der Spalte (entscheidet über ihre Reihenfolge)
     * @return TableColumn
     */
    // Das ist hier erlaubt da immer eine Typprüfung mit type.equals durchgeführt wird
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> createTableColumn(Class<T> type, String fieldName, String index, String columnHeader) {
        TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<S, T>(columnHeader);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            try {
                Object o = null;
                try {
                    o = BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().getPropertyUtils().getNestedProperty(o, fieldName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.warn(String.format("Can not reach attribute %s in %s", fieldName, cellData.getValue()), e);
                }
                // Erzeuge eine Property, die das Attribut enthält
                SimpleObjectProperty<T> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<T>((T) o);
                return property;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        if (type.equals(Boolean.TYPE))
            ((TableColumn<S, Boolean>) col).setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn((TableColumn<S, Boolean>) col));
        col.setId(index);
        return col;
    }
}
```

The Annotation

```
package company.viewfx.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD})
    /**
     * Mit dieser Annotation markierte Attribute werden in GTableView automatisch angezeigt, sofern keine anders lautenden
     * Parameter übergeben werden.
     * 
     */
    public @interface AsTableColumn {
        /**
         * @return Die Überschrift, die im Spaltenkopf angezeigt werden soll
         */
        String text() default "";

        /**
         * @return Die Stelle an der Die Spalte stehen soll
         */
        int index() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
```

TestDataModel:

```
package company.viewfx.tables.demo;

import company.viewfx.annotations.AsTableColumn;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person {
@Getter
@Setter
@AsTableColumn(index=1,text="Alive")
private boolean alive;
}
```

TestApplication:

```
package company.viewfx.tables.demo;

import company.viewfx.tables.GTableView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *         Dient der Vorführung dem Test von GTabelView
 */
public class TableTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // initialize Testdata
        ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person(true),
                new Person(false));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new GTableView<Person>(Person.class, data)));
        stage.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    provided {
        dependencies.all { dep ->
            configurations.default.exclude group: dep.group, module: dep.name
        }
    }
    compile.extendsFrom provided
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.8.3'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '2.5.6'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.osgi', name: 'org.eclipse.osgi', version: '3.7.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Your cell value factory is creating a new `ObjectProperty` every time it is called. If you change the value in the data model, that object property's value will not change. You need the cell value factory to reference the `ObjectProperty` directly defined in the model.

Comment: @James_D that is no problem to me every time the data changes it is retrieved from the DB and replaced completely but it will never be altered.
Even for my new defined ObjectProperty the checkbox should display checked or am i missing something.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [MCVE]

Comment: @James_D i did so. thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

FXML users use this as an additional column to render a checkbox.

```
<TableColumn text="Married" fx:id="married">
 <cellValueFactory>
   <PropertyValueFactory property="married" />
 </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
<fx:script>
 var myCellValue = javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(married);
 married.setCellFactory(myCellValue);
</fx:script>

 //Your data model should be exposed as below.
 private final SimpleBooleanProperty married = new    SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
 public SimpleBooleanProperty marriedProperty(){
    return married;
 }
```